# CSS adding line over speech bubble

Tags: html, css, border, outline

I have the following css for a speech bubble

Right now, I want to add an outline over the speech bubble. Does anyone have any ideas how to?

```css
.sb13:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-top: 15px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  left: -16px;
  top: 0px;
}

.box3 {
  overflow: initial !important;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: #111;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="box3 sb14">test</div>
```

Comment: I've added a normal html but the css I'm editing will go into youtube livechat popout.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `border`.

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)

```css
.sb13:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-top: 15px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  left: -16px;
  top: 0px;
}

.box3 {
  overflow: initial !important;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: #111;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box3 sb14">test</div>
```